# Dynamic Navigation menu with sub categories in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm a newbie to Laravel framework and using version 5.4. I want to create a dynamic navigation menu for my blog. and this is my database table structure for the menu.

table : categories[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uRZo.jpg)

and i used navbar as a shared file in shared folder.

I used

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
<li><a href='{{url("category/$category->slug")}}' title='{{$category->category}}'>{{$category->category}}</a></li>
@endforeach
```

code to load the categories on nav bar but unable to load sub categories. How can i do this. please tell me the way of all view, controller and model for this.

Comment: what are the sub categories?

Comment: they are in same menu which have parent_cat id !=0

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a fully featured package for that, you can have a look at [spatie's laravel menu package](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-menu)

---

**Documentation and usage**
[Here](https://docs.spatie.be/menu/v2/introduction)